# str.replace and os.rename doesn't work with file names containing "/"

Tags: python, file

I want to replace a single character on a bunch of file names with another character. However, when I want to replace files with `/` to another character, it doesn't work. It does work with other characters I want to replace, such as `-`.

The python file is on the directory path, and I 'cd' to the directory path to run the program.

I expect that every `/` on a file name would be replaced with a `_`. Like this: `file/1.txt` to `file_1.txt`.

However, the files stay the same. Like this: `file/1.txt` to `file/1.txt`.

I use this code:

```py
# Replace a character of a name file with another charater
from importlib.metadata import files
import os

counter = 0
path = r"/Users/user/test"
char = input('Enter character or string you want to replace:')
repl = input('Enter character or string you want this to be replaced with:')
files = []

# Loop, doesn't work with "/" for some reason
for file_name in os.listdir(path):
    if char in file_name :
        old_name = file_name
        new_name = file_name.replace(char, repl)
        counter += 1
        files.append(new_name)
        os.rename(old_name, new_name)
print(counter)
print(files)
print("Done! Check your files")
```

As an alternative, I deleted the variables `char` and `repl` and instead used this in the `for` loop, but it still doesn't work:

```py
for file_name in os.listdir(path):
    if "/" in file_name :
        old_name = file_name
        new_name = file_name.replace("/", "_")
        counter += 1
```

Comment: `os.listdir` just lists the file names.  It doesn't include the path so won't have any path separators in the name.  Debug by `print(file_name)` and discover this for yourself.

Comment: Does escaping the forward slash work (e.g "`\/`")?

Comment: @Vlone No it doesn't work

Comment: @MarkTolonen You're right, but I've discovered that all the files that are supposed to have a "/" on its name are showing ":" instead.

Comment: Forward slashes are not legal characters to have in a file name.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `pathlib` which is much more clean and convenient that using os module.

```
from pathlib import Path

base_folder = Path(r"/Users/user/test")

old_names = [f for f in base_folder.glob('*') if f.is_file()]
new_names = [f'{f.parts[-2]}_{f.name}' for f in old_names]

for o_name, n_name in zip(old_names, new_names):
    o_name.with_name(n_name)
```

You first create a list of file paths for all the files in the folder.

Then the second list comprehension goes through a list of files and for each file grabs its parent folder name and the file name and combines them in an f-string with _ in between.

Now, finally you go through the old and new file names and assign a new name to each of the original files.

**EDIT:**
If you want to exclude hidden files you need to amend the first comprehension to exclude files that start with a `.`:

```
old_names = [f for f in base_folder.glob('*.txt') 
             if not any(part.startswith('.') for part in f.parts) and f.is_file()]
```

Comment: Very useful and more compact, but I have run with a problem. I decided to exclude the hidden files:

Comment: @aravezskinteeth, do your hidden file have something in common? Like they start with a dot for example?

Comment: yes, they all start with dots. I tried to use this to exclude the dot files 
`old_names = [f for f in base_folder.glob('*.txt') if not any(part.startswith('.') for part in base_folder.parts) if f.is_file()]`

Comment: See updated answer. You attempt was almost correct but you needed to check parts in `f` not `base_folder` and have `and f.is_file()` instead of a separate `if`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it with this.

```py
# Replace a character of a file with another charater
from importlib.metadata import files
import os
counter = 0
path=input("Enter path: ")
char=input('Enter character or string you want to replace:')
repl=input('Enter character or string you want this to be replaced with:')
files=[]

# Ignore hidden files
def listdir_nohidden(path):
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if not f.startswith('.'):
            yield f

# Loop, instead of "/" use ":"
for file_name in listdir_nohidden(path):
    if char in file_name :
        old_name=file_name
        new_name=file_name.replace(char,repl)
        counter+=1
        files.append(new_name)
        os.rename(old_name,new_name)
print(counter)
print(files)
print("Done! Check your files")
```

Files change like this: `test/1.txt` --> `test_1.txt`
The problem was that for some reason, when I debug with `print(file_name)`, files with "/" show ":" instead. The other problem, were the hidden files, which I solved above.